# ppm to mkv/avi/mp4 converted video using ffmpeg can't be opened by Lightworks but can be viewed perfectly fine

Tags: mp4, avi, ppm, video-conversion, mkv

I am trying to make gource work for my own personal project. I set everything up and already converted the ppm output to a video file. I can open and watch the file without having any problems. But when it comes to editing the program Lightworks won't load it. I tried it with .mkv, .avi and .mp4 but it won't work.

Here's my command line command (called in a batch file):

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -vcodec ppm -f image2pipe -i render.ppm -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy gource.mkv
```

For .avi and .mp4 the error is: `Format unlicensed`
For .mkv the error is: `failed to import`

What settings should I use? Or should I use another programm?

Comment: How did you convert the PPM to a video file?

Comment: The command in my question should be working

Answer (score 0):

Lightworks is very pick about the formats it accepts (less so in recent updates), and it definitely does not accept mkv containers. These settings have worked well for me.

`avconv -i input.mkv -c:v mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -g:v 1 -q:v 1 -qmin:v 1 -c:a mp2 -r:a 48000 -b:a 384k output.mp4`

There's a more detailed explanation here: http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/convert-videos-for-import-into-lightworks-with-avconv.